# Firestore get the document but coroutine handler was called

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So im using coroutine on my project, and im trying to get a firestore Document using coroutine await function. And after i got the document, the handler was called even when the job was success. Anyone can explain to me how to fix it?

Here is my code :

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                Log.e(TAG, "saveData: $exception")
                saveData(mActivity)
            }
        }
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + handler).launch {
            val document = Firebase.firestore.collection("Users").document(getUID())
                .get().await()
            Log.d(TAG, "saveData: $document")
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val currentUser = TemplateUser(
                    getUID(),
                    document.data!!["userName"] as String,
                    document.data!!["userNIS"] as String,
                    document.data!!["userEmail"] as String,
                    document.data!!["userKelas"] as String,
                    document.data!!["kuisSatu"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisSatuAttempt"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisDua"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisDuaAttempt"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisTiga"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisTigaAttempt"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisEmpat"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisEmpatAttempt"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisLima"] as Long,
                    document.data!!["kuisLimaAttempt"] as Long
                )
                Log.d(TAG, "saveData: $currentUser")

            val sharedPreferences =
                mActivity.getSharedPreferences("userProfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            with(sharedPreferences) {
                putString("userName", currentUser.userName)
                putString("userEmail", currentUser.userEmail)
                putString("userNIS", currentUser.userNIS)
                putString("userKelas", currentUser.userKelas)
                putLong("kuisSatu", currentUser.kuisSatu)
                putLong("kuisDua", currentUser.kuisDua)
                putLong("kuisTiga", currentUser.kuisTiga)
                putLong("kuisEmpat", currentUser.kuisEmpat)
                putLong("kuisLima", currentUser.kuisLima)
                putLong("kuisSatuAttempt", currentUser.kuisSatuAttempt)
                putLong("kuisDuaAttempt", currentUser.kuisDuaAttempt)
                putLong("kuisTigaAttempt", currentUser.kuisTigaAttempt)
                putLong("kuisEmpatAttempt", currentUser.kuisEmpatAttempt)
                putLong("kuisLimaAttempt", currentUser.kuisLimaAttempt)
                apply()
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "saveData: Sharepref berhasil diisi dengan data $document")
            GreetUser.greetUser(mActivity)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: Thats why im also confused. The coroutine success on getting the task, but coroutine exception handler was called after the task is done

Comment: So you basically say that you get a success, as well as a failure from the same operation? Can you prove that?

Comment: I put a log to display the document after it was successfull. And the log display the result normally. But then the error log on handler was called and says java null pointer exception. But this case is only happened on Oppo smartphone, so i dont really know what is wrong on this

Comment: On any other phones or emulators, works correctly?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine on my Redmi Note 7 and my friends Google Pixel 3